# Strange "The entity type CUSTOM_ENTITY is not part of the model for the current context." exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

this problem started happening suddenly. This is a **database first** data model. When I created it using an existing database, this class was generated ‍`DataModel.Context.cs` file‍‍‍:

```
public partial class MyModelEntities : DbContext
{
    public MyModelEntities ()
        : base("name=MyModelEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<ACGroup> ACGroup { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ACTimeZones> ACTimeZones { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ACUnlockComb> ACUnlockComb { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AttParam> AttParam { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AuditedExc> AuditedExc { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AUTHDEVICE> AUTHDEVICE { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<CHECKEXACT> CHECKEXACT { get; set; }
}
```

Then, I try to use this code to make a query over some entity:

```
using (MyModelEntities db = new MyModelEntities())
{
    var checkinOut = db.AUTHDEVICE.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

When I run that code, this error occurs:

> System.InvalidOperationException:
> The entity type AUTHDEVICE is not part of the model for the current
> context.

Intellisense finds that entity correctly when I type that instruction, and if I browse to AUTHDEVICE definition, the `DataModel.Context.cs` content is shown.

The `AUTHDEVICE.cs` file contains this and I can browse to it too:

```
public partial class AUTHDEVICE
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int USERID { get; set; }
    public int MachineID { get; set; }
}
```

I don't know what may be happening here. I even removed and recreate the model but no avail. What else can I try?

This happen with ALL entities in the model.

EDIT: Other test I have just done:

I have added this code inside the `using` statement:

```
var query = db.Database.SqlQuery<AUTHDEVICE>("SELECT * FROM AUTHDEVICE");
var check = query.FirstOrDefault();
```

And it worked! But I need to do it in the other way.

EDIT: AUTHDEVICE script:

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[AUTHDEVICE]    Script Date: 10-10-2022 16:43:04 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AUTHDEVICE](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [USERID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [MachineID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [AUTHKEY] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [USERID] ASC,
    [MachineID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Thanks
Jaime

Comment: Thanks, but it seems I did not explain myself well. The problem is not the database connection nor the query itself, but the model imported to Visual Studio. `AUTHDEVICE` entity is not recognized as part of the model, even when that entity actually is in the model.

Comment: I am not sure why you are not sure. That is the normal way to use EF..... for example, `context.Entity`. `Entity` is mapped to a table in the database. With that I should be able to do all operations against it. In this VS solution I am using 2 more databases with no problems (in other projects). The database in this project has this kind of problem. If there is no way to solve this, I will try to recreate the project.

Comment: I can't really think of anything that could be wrong. It's pretty rare to get this error when using EDMX. But maybe you could take this as an opportunity to move to code-first (without migrations) and be more future-ready.

Comment: could you please share your database table `AUTHDEVICE` script.

Comment: @MD.RAKIBHASAN I updated the question. When I first created the model in the project it worked, however, sometimes it stopped working. I am already removed and recreated the model and it continues not working. If intellisense recognize the AUTHDEVICE entity is part of the context, maybe at some time database mapping was gone. I have even change context name, but no avail. In the same solution I have a context of other database and it works.

Comment: @jstuardo This exception is generic, it could have a number of reasons. It can be connection string issue as well. Can you share your connection string?

Comment: @DilshodK There you are: `<add name="Att2000Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataModel.csdl|res://*/DataModel.ssdl|res://*/DataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=localhost;initial catalog=ATT2000;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />`

Comment: @DilshodK Finally I used `context.Database.SqlQuery` to do the queries and `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` to do an `INSERT`. Ugly solution but it works. Even when it worked, it would be interesting to know what was causing this. I tried to debug inside .NET code but no avail.

Comment: Can you try simple ADO.NET connection string, like <add name="Att2000Entities" connectionString="data source=localhost;initial catalog=ATT2000;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

Comment: I believe the model first method is no longer supported.

Answer (score 1):

The scenario you are describing, can be reproduced by

1. creating a `DbContext` via model first approach
2. adding the `AUTHDEVICE` table manually to the database
3. adding the `AUTHDEVICE` class and the context property manually to the code

Renaming a (mistyped) existing entity in steps 2 & 3 would yield the same result.

Now, when you access `db.AUTHDEVICE` you'll get the described error and when you use `db.Database.SqlQuery<AUTHDEVICE>("SELECT * FROM AUTHDEVICE")` you'll get all records from the database.

Can you please verify, that the `AUTHDEVICE` table is contained in the diagram shown when you open the edmx file. If it is not (or not spelled correctly), then a manual edit is likely to be the solution and you should use the `Update Model from Database` option available when right-clicking on an empty spot in the edmx-diagram. This might make manual refactoring of your code necessary as I doubt, that changes to the database are automatically refactored.

Or you change to code first approach, but then you will have to apply the following changes:

- replace the *model first* connectionstring with the embedded *real* connection string (starting at "data source..." and ending "...;App=EntityFramework")
- remove the line `throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();` from the `OnModelCreating` method
- manually define all table and column properties which are now set in edmx (like table names, key properties, NULLables, string lengths, ...). You can do that via `DataAnnotations` on your entity properties (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/data-annotations) or in the `OnModelCreating` method via fluent syntax (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/types-and-properties).
- remove all edmx stuff, but keep the generated entity and dbcontext code